Phaser.js Axios Timing Issue When Changing Scenes
Is there a way to make an axios get call inside my Phaser 3 code, and then load a new scene with the response data? At the moment, I am having a kind of timing issue where I think the second scene gets loaded before the axios call can return a response? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code. First, inside my SelectDifficultyScene js file:
preload()
{
    this.fetchSudoku();
    
    // this.scene.start(GameScene, this.sudoku);
}

async fetchSudoku()
{
    self = this;
    
    console.log("Select Difficulty Scene");

    try
    {
        const response = await axios.get('api/fetch-sudoku');
        console.log("Select Difficulty Scene", self.sudoku);
        self.setSudoku(response.data);
        self.loadGameScene();
        // const gameScene = new GameScene();
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

setSudoku(sudoku)
{
    this.sudoku.unsolvedSudoku = sudoku.unsolvedSudoku;
    this.sudoku.solvedSudoku = sudoku.solvedSudoku;
    this.sudoku.difficultyLevel = "Easy";
}

loadGameScene()
{
    this.scene.start('GameScene', this.sudoku);
}

Then, inside my GameScene file:
init(sudoku)
{
    // console.log(sudoku);
    this.setSudokuNumbers(sudoku);
}

setSudokuNumbers(sudoku)
{
    let unsolvedCount = 0;
    let solvedCount = 0;
    for(let x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for(let y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            this.sudokuGridUnsolved[x][y] = sudoku.unsolvedSudoku[unsolvedCount];
            this.sudokuGridSolved[x][y] = sudoku.solvedSudoku[solvedCount];
            unsolvedCount++;
            solvedCount++;
        }
    }
    
    // console.log(sudoku, this.sudokuGrid);
}

When I load both scenes inside my game config file, GameScene gets loaded and I see no response data inside my dev tools. When I remove GameScene from game config and try again, I get the correct response data loaded?

can you share the relevant code the produces the problem (or a MRE)? Since your question posses many follow-up question. Like: where in the code should the call occur? should the code pause the current scene, until the callback executes or not ? what is the response data is it relevant for calling the next scene? how should the next scene be started? ...?

...I almost forgot, how do you notice/define this "timing issue"?

In my game config, when I declare both scenes, the second scene gets loaded instantly and I notice no response data? But when I only declare the first scene in my config, I see the response data get loaded in my dev tools?

Can you share the relevant code / example? it is not clear when and where you are loading the Scene or when you are using? axios.

I updated my answer with a working example, I hope this helps.

I think the issue is the order in which you loading the scenes in your config, but wihtout seeing it I'm just guessing.
The order matters in the array, in the first code snippet GameScene is loaded and displayed first. SelectDifficultyScene is loaded but not started/displayed.
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    ...
    scene: [ GameScene, SelectDifficultyScene ]
};

Switching the order of the scenes should solve your problem, if I understud you setup correct.
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    ...
    scene: [ SelectDifficultyScene, GameScene ]
};

Update
(small working demo)


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('FirstScene');
    }
    
    create(){
        let label = this.add.text(10,10, 'FirstScene\n... please wait')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
        setTimeout( _ =>
          axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
            .then((response) => {
              this.scene.start('SecondScene', response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              label.setText(` First Scene\nError: ${error}`);
            }), 
        2000);
    }
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('SecondScene');
        console.info(this);
    }
    
    create(data){
    
        let label = this.add.text(10,10, 'SecondScene')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
            
        let dataLabel = this.add.text(10, 40, JSON.stringify(data))
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setWordWrapWidth(300)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});   
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene],
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.21.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Sounds as simple as that:
class Scene extends Phaser.Scene {
  ...
  async create() {
    ...
    const data = await axios.get('your-endpoint-url')
    this.scene.launch('your-next-scene-key', { data })
  }
}

If you need to shutdown the current scene, you should use .start method instead of .launch
